# Safari - not to download existing files

Tags: safari

Is there a way for safari to not download something if it already exists in my Downloads folder? Or if you can't do that, can you make it so that it asks you if you are sure you want to download it?

I know I have the downloads history button, but that doesn't show the pdfs you download when viewing them online. I always have trouble figuring out if I pressed the arrow to download them or not.

It is very annoying because I end up downloading 5 copies of the same file and the only way I have of checking if I've downloaded it is by checking the folder itself, which is a hassle when the point is to read them online and keep a copy as back up and nothing more.

Just to reiterate, I am talking about pdfs that you are reading in Safari and press the download button to get, not things that show up in your Download's history.

Thanks for any help you might have!

Comment: I know this does not answer your question but I set the download location to the desktop, so I immediately see what I downloaded and a quick command-H will show me what is there. I mention this because I am doubtful that there exists a preference to do what you want.